# Error during running app in Android Studio 2.3.3

Tags: android, android-studio, build.gradle

I was trying to to resolve an error concerning "FirebaseListOptions" so i followed some topics and i changed my build.gradle file. The "FirebaseListOptions" error was solved but when running the app this error appeared :

> Error:Execution failed for task
>   ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.
>
> > com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException:
> >     java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.dex.DexException:
> >     Multiple dex files define Landroid/arch/lifecycle/ViewModel;

here is **build.gradle file** :

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    buildToolsVersion "27.0.3"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.bilel.ids.easycom"
        minSdkVersion 22
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.+'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'


    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'

    //add Library
    compile 'com.android.support:design:27.+'
    compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui:1.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.4.2'
    compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:3.1.0'
    compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:3.1.0'

}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
configurations {
    all*.exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-v4'

}
```

And the change that I made is adding this 3 lines:

```
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.4.2'
compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:3.1.0'
compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:3.1.0
```

Comment: You need to seriously update your things like Android Studio, Dependencies, SDK and SDK Tools

Answer (score 0):

try to add this dependencies on your gradle

```
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'

implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.1'

implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'

//firebase stuff
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.8.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:11.8.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.8.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.8.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.8.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:11.8.0'
```

Comment: i got this message when project sync : 
'Error:(44, 0) Could not find method implementation() for arguments [directory 'libs'] on object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.'

Comment: Are you using Android Studio 3.0 or above?

Comment: I am using Android Studio 2.3.3

Comment: I just updated Android Studio from 2.2.3 to 3.2 and i still have the error message appearing